# Import Error: No Module Name filter error in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm facing the following problem while running the code. Please help me I am doing this in Anaconda and I have installed all essential libraries.

File "C:\Users\Hanzala Iqbal\Desktop\LSTM-RNN-for-Traffic-Prediction-in-Cellular-Networks-master\ntpa.py", line 36, in 
import filters

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filters'

```
I am trying to run the code but "No modul name filter" is occuring
```

Comment: Is the module filter installed on anaconda for you ?

Comment: yes the module filter is installed